# Does D&D Next or Dead in Thay have rules for equipping new PCs above level 1?

Tags: character-creation, dnd-encounters, dnd-next-playtest

My game group at the local shop recently got our hand on the next season of D&D Encounters, Dead in Thay, and will be running it in a few days.

Previous editions, such as 4e, have very specific rules and guidelines for character creation at higher levels, giving PCs magic items and more gold based on what level they start at.

Do PCs in D&D Next created at a level higher than 1st receive additional gold or items? If not, are there any D&D Encounters rules for Next for how to equip starting PCs in higher-level Encounters seasons?

Comment: Since D&D encounters is not its own system and I specifically mentioned both the campaign and D&D Encounters in the question, I don't think its unreasonable to tag Encounters to rely that I am looking for Encounters specific rules as well.

Comment: [Related] [What's the starting wealth for higher levels?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69105) (But not duplicate, I think, since this covers AL and that is implicitly about home games.)

Comment: When you mention items, are you thinking specifically magic items? Or also mundane items that they don't get right away? (Like Plate armor for a Fighter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, No Better Items for Higher Level PCs**

> No rules of the game assume that characters must have a certain amount of treasure or gear by a certain level... The key thing is to make sure the players feel rewarded for playing, and feel like their characters are rewarded for taking on dangerous challenges (DM Guidelines, page 18)

It does appear that the treasure tables do rely on the encounter or monster's level, so higher-level encounters should give you more loot, which will rectify that problem more quickly. (DM Guidelines, also page 18)

Additionally, no mention is made in "Character Creation" about anything other than starting equipment.

Comment: I figured it was a no, since I scanned through the playtest docs and the encounters docs I had and found nothing.

Comment: I can confirm that none of the level 6 pregen characters have more equipment than they could get at level 1.

Comment: Now that the 5e DMG is out, does this answer still hold up?

Answer (score 1):

They (WOTC) didn't release much for magic items and treasure until the final playtest. From what I saw, they want magic items to matter, but the focus to be on the characters. That said, even with the fact that encounters have started, the official book release typically waits for the DMG to put out those guidelines.

If you don't mind the work, calculate the average amount of treasure the characters would get by the level you want them to be, and reduce it by roughly 25%. That reduction accounts for maintenance and expendables.