# Which equipment list does a multiclass character choose from when starting at a higher level?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment, multi-classing

I'm creating a new Level 10 Character who is starting off multi-classing.  Each class has the following equipment:

Class #1

> - (a) a handaxe and a light hammer or (b) any
>     two simple weapons
> - a light crossbow and 20 bolts
> - (a) scale mail or (b) studded leather armor
> - thieves’ tools and a dungeoneer’s pack

Class #2

> - (a) two shortswords or (b) a shortsword and
>     shield
> - A quarterstaff and light armor
> - Your choice of gaming set
> - An ancient tome and a explorer’s pack

When selecting my starting equipment, do I get everything, mix and match (take hand axe and light hammer from Class #1, then quarterstaff and light armor from Class #2), or everything from one which class that he started as?

I know the DM can decide any of those, but what is the rule?

Comment: [Related] [Do you get the equipment of your new class when you multi-class?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55396)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your starting equipment is your equipment you start with at first level. Gaining a level in another class adds no additional equipment.

[Player's Handbook errata](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf) clarifies this:

> ### Multiclassing
>
> **Class Features (p. 164).** You gain the
>   starting equipment of your first class only

Another question might be that a level 10 character should have more advanced equipment than a starting one, which is  intended to be used by level 1 characters. That's covered in the question [What's the starting wealth for higher levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69105/whats-the-starting-wealth-for-higher-levels)