# Is the necklace of fireballs underpriced in the Sane Magic Items pdf?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, pricing

I gave my third-level party 900gp and told them they could buy start equipment from the Sane Magic Items pdf.

One of my characters bought a two-bead Necklace of Fireballs and personally demolished two combats.  (He rolled high in initiative and the monsters were grouped up.)  I wasn't thrilled with this considering I was running a one-shot.

Now, I'm in a different game (also a one-shot, but much higher level) and all of us have independently bought a bunch of Necklaces of Fireballs with some of our starting cash.

Is this broken?  This feels broken.  Is there anything we can say about this, other than "consumable items should cost more if you're doing a one-shot"?

Comment: What is your metric for "should?" Also, why not just space put the enemies a bit and throw in some fire resistance?

Comment: You let your 3rd level party by 3rd level spells and you blame the item?

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm not much of a fan of of that pdf. For instance, a Weapon of Warning (uncommon) is more than twice as much as a Vorpal Sword (legendary)? The opposite of what it claims to be, that's insane.

Comment: @RallozarX eh, vorpal sword has maybe a 1/3 chance of actually changing something per fight. Initiative bonus? That can save you, while a vorpal blade can't.

Comment: @ Dan B To be clear, all the affected games were one-shots?

@RallozarX Vorpal Sword is really fun to have but if I would want to optimize, I'd take weapon of warning any day - especially it doesn't even have to be used, just to be on your person.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### One-shot or not, it is the amount of money your players had that is the problem, not the prices

**Let us begin by looking at starting gold**

At level 1 the wealthiest a character can be is a lucky Bard, Cleric, Fighter, Paladin or Ranger. These classes have an option to start with 5d4 x 10 which maxes out at 200 gold pieces.

That gold is used if they don't take starting gear, so they still have to buy weapons and armour. Generally classes are better off just taking starting equipment, armour and instruments are pricy!

Your players had more than 4 times this amount (900 gold pieces!), and seemingly didn't have to buy other gear, or maybe they were naked with just fireballs.

**But your characters were level 3! What difference should that make?**

The DMG gives us some guidance, and while I can't replicate the chart here (mainly because I don't know how), the answer is 'it makes no difference'. Any character starting in tier 1 (being level 1-4) is recommended to only have starting gear - even in a high magic setting.

In fact from the low magic, average and high magic settings, the first time a magic item is recommended is for tier 2 characters (being level 5-9) in a high magic setting. Also that would only be an uncommon item, but anyone using Sane Magic Items is already ignoring rarity, as I would recommend.

Other lesser magical settings allow for a few hundred additional gold, but no magic items. And for most classes, that gold would just be spent on an armour upgrade.

What you have done here is found a problem, but rather than analyse the problem itself you have immediately places Sane Magic Items as the culprit, but that isn't true.

**What else could have been bought?**

Let us assume you never used the Sane Magic Item list, your players could have bought, with just RAW PHB prices, 18 basic healing potions each. That would also have rendered the encounters trivial, although not quite as spectacularly.

In fact it is this comparison that helped set the price in the first place. I don't know how much damage your party would have taken without the fireballs, but if it was less than 18 health potions worth of damage each then actually the fireballs might have been overpriced!

### Sane magic items isn't intended to be used by the insane*

The guide is intended to give a price comparison for magic items against one another, it is not intended to help you set an economy, and if you are going to give your players a slush fund the onus is on you as a DM to ensure that slush fund is reasonable.

I would also recommend running a trained eye over what they decide to buy even when you are giving a 'balanced' amount of money. Magic items are not normally just for sale like that, and having a free pick at character creation can lead to some unbalanced builds and a power gamers paradise.

I remember recently in a 1 shot my paladin got a holy avenger, and despite it being one of the best and most valuable items in the game I was actually a little disappointed, because I could have spent that money and got far more value *in my specific case*. For example I was already rolling with advantage on saves vs magic and what we were fighting were unaffected by the extra damage. In a normal campaign dropping this would have made me exceptionally happy!

Unfortunately, that is on you, not on the sane magic items guide.

**Play on words, don't take it personally.*

### Finally, one shots have their own problems

A one shot adventure, by design is meant to be completed quickly. That means they tend not to have the recommended amount of encounters per day (because combat is the slowest part of the game usually), which means the party resources are not usually spread as thinly as in a proper campaign.

Giving the players additional items of any kind will only make this worse.

### Advice for balancing starting money

Olorin made a comment about a wealth by level chart, which I understand was something 3.5e used, but isn't really a thing in 5th edition. However I have seen some analysis of the expected gains based on the tables in the DMG ([such as this one](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/dungeon-masters-only/79378-character-wealth-gold-by-level)) and they are a good place to start.

This particular linked table recommends 188gp for a level 3 character.

Comment: That's generally a good answer, but it doesn't touch the important thing that OP is talking about one-shots, and Sane Magic Item list was (probably) compiled with normal length campaigns in mind.

Comment: @Mołot not really, 900g is a LOT of money to give a third level party,  even 100 extra gold would be generous. the sane magic item list works fine if you don't give your party an unreasonable fortune to spend.

Comment: @John An answer discussing what you just said would be helpful, along with mentioning the wealth/level rules.

Comment: @Olorin there are no real wealth / level rules in 5e other than starting equipment (which I have now covered above). 3.5 had a proper wealth / level chart if I understand it right.

Comment: @SeriousBri not true, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69105/whats-the-starting-wealth-for-higher-levels

Comment: @John that is the starting wealth I reference in the answer, it isn't really a wealth / level table in the way that 3.5 had and that I assumed (maybe wrongly) that Olorin was referring to, but is very valid to this question nevertheless.